# Elixir/Phoenix Trying function multiple times, catching on :ok

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a function `ping()` that results in either `{:ok}` or `{:error}`.

Is it possible to make a wrapping function `test()`, that will try `ping()` 5 times, before returning an error, unless one of those `ping()` responds with `{:ok}`?

If `test()` can return `{:ok}` from `ping()` on the first try, then it should exit recursion, but if not, then continuing trying `ping()` for another 4 times.

I have checked [try/catch](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html), but can't seem to figure how to make it work. Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `try`/`catch` here. A simple recursive function with a `case` statement to match the response is enough:

```
defmodule A do
  # A function that returns `{:ok}` a third of the times it's called.
  def ping, do: if :random.uniform(3) == 1, do: {:ok}, else: {:error}

  # 5 attempts.
  def test(), do: test(5)

  # If 1 attempt is left, just return whatever `ping` returns.
  def test(1), do: ping()
  # If more than one attempts are left.
  def test(n) do
    # Print remaining attempts for debugging.
    IO.inspect {n}
    # Call `ping`.
    case ping() do
      # Return {:ok} if it succeeded.
      {:ok} -> {:ok}
      # Otherwise recurse with 1 less attempt remaining.
      {:error} -> test(n - 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```
iex(1)> A.test
{5}
{4}
{3}
{2}
{:ok}
iex(2)> A.test
{5}
{4}
{3}
{2}
{:error}
iex(3)> A.test
{5}
{:ok}
iex(4)> A.test
{5}
{:ok}
iex(5)> A.test
{5}
{4}
{:ok}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Exactly what I was looking for. Have a nice day!